# solving for a race condition in rails ( limited number of X in Y )

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, locking, race-condition

Edit: Using MySQL...

Say you have an app that adds students to a class, and that class has limited space... so you do something like this:

```
def add
  if some_classroom.size < MAX_SIZE
    add_student_to_class
  end
end
```

That's a race condition in a multi-threaded environment. Lame.

Assuming we

1. don't want this, and
2. don't want to lock our classroom table or record (which causes our app to suck elsewhere)

What do we do?

I propose this:

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :classroom_lock
  after_create :create_lock_record

  def create_lock_record
    c = ClassroomLock.new
    c.classroom = self
    c.save!
  end
end

class ClassroomLock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
end

def add
  c = Classroom.first
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    c.classroom_lock.lock!
    c = Classroom.first #load this again (it might have changed)
    if c.size < MAX_SIZE
      c.add_new_student(some_student)
    else
      do_stuff_about_not_enough_room
    end
  end
end
```

This seems like it should work awesomely.  My (ficticious) Classroom#show method doesn't block because the classroom record isn't actually locked and the add method is effectively single threaded since any additional processes will be forced to wait at the lock! line until the lock is released.

Does this work?  Maybe? I think so?  I don't know...

I've done a fair bit of hammering this with multiple processes at once, but it's hard to know for sure (it is a race condition after all).

Can anyone provide some additional insight?

Comment: Use `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. Throw your hand-rolled solution out and see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking

Comment: I rolled this:  def rockout! ; ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do ; u = User.lock("LOCK IN SHARE MODE").first ; sleep 5 ; u.email = "foo#{Time.now.to_i}@foo.com" ; u.save! ; end ; end

Comment: ...and executed it in two separate consoles.. The second one resulted in a deadlock.  so, negative :/

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Comment: ...also probably better to make suggestions as answers instead of comments

Comment: Did you ever establish whether this worked? I feel as though I need something very similar to solve a find_or_create (sort of) race condition I have.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

I imagine a pretty easy SQL-approach with just one caveat: add an additional column called something like `list_position` and add a unique index to the classroom-student-relation-table consisting of `classroom_id`, `student_id` and `list_position`.

Inserting than happens by setting `list_position` to the number of students in class plus one. Ruby code would probably be somewhere along

```ruby
classroomStudent = ClassroomStudent.new
classroomStudent.list_position = classroom.size + 1
until classroomStudent.save
  classroomStudent.list_position += 1
  do_stuff_about_not_enough_room if classroomStudent.list_position > MAX_SIZE
end
```

Result: If two inserts try to insert a student into the same class at the same time the unique index will keep one student out (`INSERT` fails). This means you may have to retry until `list_position=MAX_SIZE`, but are guaranteed you will never have too many students in class.
You could also use this approach to build up a waiting-queue.

If you already have data in your relation-table you will have to add a value for `list_position` first. I would guess something like

```sql
UPDATE ClassroomStudents AS c1 SET c1.list_position = COALESCE((SELECT MAX(c2.list_position) FROM ClassroomStudents AS c2 WHERE c2.classroom_id = c1.classroom_id), 0) + 1;
```

would do the job here although it might be a bit on the slow side.

I know the solution still has some rough edges, but maybe it helps.

Regards

TC